# Default custom realm in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Our team is working on a project that integrates into Keycloak. We created a custom realm, say `ProjectX` and enable our custom theme on it to be applied in the login page of Keycloak.

Since our theme is applied on the realm `ProjectX` and not in `master`, then how can we default the custom realm to be displayed(with the theme) when we first access the keycloak login page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which project you are building and how you are configure keycloak in your `ProjectX` project. Ok lets ignore all these thing and see how we generally browse keycloak .We Simply hit `https://<IP ADDRESS>:<PORT>/auth` then it will show some link and we click to `Administration Console` and it will redirect to `MASTER` realm url.

Which look like this `https://<IP ADDRESS>:<PORT>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F135.250.138.93%3A8666%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F%3Fredirect_fragment%3D%252Frealms%252Fbasic-auth%252Ftheme-settings&state=47381ff9-eb03-4419-bac3-8824d57f9c0d&nonce=be95ef5a-0737-49a3-be0b-4577f7a050ae&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid`

Now in your case you want to access the url for particular realm and not default(Master) realm,So here is the Solution hit below url.

```
https://<IP ADDRESS>:<PORT>/auth/realms/<REALM-NAME>/account
```

But make sure you created user for your realm and give proper rights to particular user.

Comment: Yes thats right! Thank you. I just realize that realms are isolated and has its own log in page link accessing the client `account`.